# Enter the default month and day with a prefixed year mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1292

Hi I have this code and I have been asked for this query: Surname of the actors in alphabetical order, with the titles of the films in which they participated, and their age at
time of participation in film production (conventionally dated 30 June);

I have tried in every way the datediff function but it keeps giving me error, from what I understand does not accept the production year written in that way. How do I set the month and day as a query and then use the datediff? thank you very much for those who will help me, I'm wasting my time for nonsense. Excuse me but I'm still in the beginning

```
    create database cinema;
use cinema;
create table participation(film varchar (3) not null ,actor varchar(5) not null);
create table actor (id_actor varchar(5) not null,name varchar(30), surname varchar(30) not null);
create table film (id_film varchar(3) not null,title varchar(30) not null, kind varchar (30) not null, producer varchar (5) not null, production_year year(4));
create table producer( id_producer varchar (5) not null, name varchar (30) ,surname varchar(30) not null);
alter table producer add primary key (id_producer);
alter table film add primary key (id_film);
alter table participation add primary key (film,actor);
alter table actor add primary key (id_actor);
alter table participation add constraint fk_pfilm foreign key (film) references film(id_film);
alter table participation add constraint fk_pactor foreign key (actor) references actor(id_actor);
alter table film add constraint fk_fproducer foreign key (producer) references producer (id_producer);

insert into producer(id_producer,name,surname) values ("0000A","Steven","Spielberg"),("0000B","Stanley","Kubrick"),("0000C","Ridley","Scott");
insert into actor(id_actor,name,surname) values ("000AA","Sylvester","Stallone"),("000AB","Brad","Pitt"),
("000AC","George","Clooney"),("000AD","Demi","Moore"),("000AE","Bruce","Willis"),
("000AF","Monica","Bellucci");
insert into film(id_film,title,kind,production_year,producer) values ("00A","Jurassic Park","avventura",'2000',"0000A"),("00B","Matrix","fantascienza",'2001',"0000B"),
("00C","Star Wars","fantascienza",'2000',"0000A"),("00D","Indiana Jones","avventura",'2002',"0000B"),("00E","Rambo","avventura",'2002',"0000A"),
("00F","Rocky I","sportivo",'2001',"0000A"),("00G","Rocky II","sportivo",'2004',"0000B");
insert into participation (film,actor) values ("00A","000AA"),("00B","000AB"),("00C","000AC"),("00D","000AD"),("00E","000AA"),
("00F","000AA"),("00G","000AB"),("00A","000AC"),("00B","000AA"),("00C","000AB"),("00D","000AB");

select * from participation;
select * from actor;
select * from film;
select * from producer;

alter table actor add column datebirth date;
update actor set datebirth='1946-07-06' where id_actor="000AA";
update actor set datebirth='1963-12-18' where id_actor="000AB";
update actor set datebirth='1961-05-06' where id_actor="000AC";
update actor set datebirth='1962-11-11' where id_actor="000AD";
update actor set datebirth='1955-03-19' where id_actor="000AE";
update actor set datebirth='1964-09-30' where id_actor="000AF";


create view vista as select * from (actor inner join participation on id_actor=participation.actor);
create view vista2 as select * from (vista inner join film on vista.film=film.id_film);
select surname,title,datediff(datebirth,production_year-06-30) as età from vista2;
```

Comment: If you provide english table names, column names and data it would be more logical for non italian speakers/readers because iám pretty sure nobody is going to do all that trouble and Google translate it.   and [text formatted results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) so we can verify if the query we write is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `anno_produzione-06-30` with:

```
concat(anno_produzione, '-06-30')
```

The engine can cast ISO date representations to `date`.

And you shouldn't use double quotes around string literals. Use singles quotes instead, that's their job in SQL.

Comment: Perfect thank you! One last thing: how can I see this age difference in years?

Comment: @GiacomoCorcella to get the difference in years use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, datebirth,CONCAT(production_year, '-06-30')`